# bool array and for loop in Arduino

Tags: arduino

I have an array

```
int lc[2][2]=
  {
    {HIGH,LOW},
    {LOW,HIGH}
  };
```

and I want to create a for loop with

```
for(lc[2][2]==HIGH){...}
```

but it only works for

```
for(lc[1][1]==HIGH){...}
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two-dimensional array consist of two rows and two columns.

You can access the values with **lc[0][0]** and **lc[1][1]**.

You have not assigned the index 2 a value, so you would not get into the loop.